# Can java.vendor.url be modified from the command line?

Tags: java

Trying to come up with a hack/workaround for a Slf4j [check](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/v_1.7.30/slf4j-api/src/main/java/org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.java#L145), needed for a complicated Vert.x module class loader configuration, I was thinking I could modify the `java.vendor.url` system property, but it doesn't seem to work from the command line, using `-Djava.vendor.url=android`.

It can be changed from Java code, but it's too late by then and Slf4j prints the annoying warning and I wouldn't go to something as complicated as a JVM agent.

Is there any way to change it from the command line that I haven't seen?

Answer (score 1):

From documentation of `setProperty`:

> **Changing a standard system property may have unpredictable results unless otherwise specified.**

A JVM Agent is not that complicated <sub>(just enough to not make it a comment)</sub>:

```
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class Agent {

    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {
        System.setProperty("java.vendor.url", "my url");
    }
}
```

Manifest file `manifest.txt`:

```
Premain-Class: Agent
```

and put it into a JAR:
`jar cfm agent.jar manifest.txt Agent.class`

use like in:
`java -javaagent:agent.jar ...`

Based on javadoc of [java.lang.instrument](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html)

<sub>maybe some possible trouble regarding permissions or so...</sub>
<sub>*names, packages, ... missing on this post to keep it simple*</sub>

Comment: Sure, but it's still more overhead than what I was hoping for...